# React useCallback linting error missing dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a custom hook `useInstantSearch` in my component.

When I wrap it in `useCallback` to I get the following error:

```
React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead.
```

This is the code:

```
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>(searchQuery);
  const handleDebouncedSearch = useCallback(
    useInstantSearch(searchTerm, (search, cancelTrigger, searchStillValid) => {
      console.log('instant search', search);
    }),
    []
  );

  useEffect((): void => {
    handleDebouncedSearch(searchTerm);
  }, [searchTerm, handleDebouncedSearch]);
```

So effectively to send the updated search term to a child component for display only then the parent handles the debouncing of the search when that term changes.

```
search, cancelTrigger, searchStillValid
```

Are not part of the parent component, they are part of `useInstantSearch`.

Is this a warning I can ignore?

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { CancelTrigger } from '../../../ars/api/api.cancel';

const DELAY_SEARCH_MS = 300;

interface InstantSearchOnChange {
  (search: string, cancelTrigger: CancelTrigger, resultStillValid: { (): boolean }): void;
}

/**
 * Helper to delay request until user stop typing (300ms), support deprecated requests (cancel and helper to not update the state), or unmounted component.
 */
export default function useInstantSearch(initialSearch: string, onChange: InstantSearchOnChange): { (value: string): void } {
    
  const search = useRef<string>(initialSearch);
  const requests = useRef<CancelTrigger[]>([]);

  const mounted = useRef<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    return (): void => {
      mounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return value => {
    search.current = value;

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (search.current === value) {
        requests.current = requests.current.filter(r => !r.cancel());

        const trigger = new CancelTrigger();
        requests.current.push(trigger);

        onChange(value, trigger, () => search.current === value && mounted.current);
      }
    }, DELAY_SEARCH_MS);
  };
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to use hook within another hook?

Comment: I am not sure how else to use it.  I need to update searchTerm immediately for the user but then debounce the call to the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore it if you don't mind the [stale closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) you can do it that way:

```js
const { useRef, useCallback, useEffect } = React;
const DELAY_SEARCH_MS = 300;
const later = (value, time) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value), time)
  );
/**
 * Helper to delay request until user stop typing (300ms), support deprecated requests (cancel and helper to not update the state), or unmounted component.
 */
function useInstantSearch(onChange) {
  const timeout = useRef();
  const mounted = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      mounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
  return useCallback(
    (value) => {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current); //cancel other
      timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
        const current = timeout.current;
        onChange(
          value,
          () =>
            //comparing timeout.current with current
            //  async function may not be the last to resolve
            //  this is important when you want to set state based
            //  on an async result that is triggered on user input
            //  user types "a" and then "b" if 2 async searches start
            //  "a" and "ab" and "a" is so slow it will resolve after "ab"
            //  then state result will be set for "ab" first and then with "a"
            //  causing UI to be out of sync because user searched for "ab"
            //  but results for "a" are shown
            timeout.current === current && mounted.current
        );
      }, DELAY_SEARCH_MS);
    },
    [onChange]
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const handler1 = useCallback(
    (value) => console.log('handler1:', value),
    []
  );
  const handler2 = useCallback(
    (value) => console.log('handler2:', value),
    []
  );
  const handler3 = useCallback((value, shouldResolve) => {
    console.log('starting async with:', value);
    return later(
      value,
      value.length === 1 ? 1000 : 800
    ).then(
      (resolve) =>
        shouldResolve() &&//you can opt not to set state here
        console.log('resolved with', resolve)
    );
  }, []);
  const debounced1 = useInstantSearch(handler1);
  const debounced2 = useInstantSearch(handler2);
  const debounced3 = useInstantSearch(handler3);
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(
    (num) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        debounced1(num);
        debounced2(num * 2);
      }, 100) //lower than the 300 of debounce
  );
  //both callbacks will be called but "a" resolves after "ab" since
  //  "ab" was the last to be requested it will be the only one that logs
  //  resolved with
  setTimeout(() => debounced3('a'), 500);
  setTimeout(() => debounced3('ab'), 1500);
  return 'hello world (check console)';
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

There may be a solution to your problem but without knowing what `useInstantSearch` is it's impossible to provide one.

My guess is that you should use `useCallback` inside `useInstantSearch` but since that code is missing from your question I can only guess.

Comment: @RyanP13 why pass `useInstantSearch` to `useInstantSearch` when you never use it? You set it to a ref but then reset it as soon as you use the ref: `search.current = value`. Not passing it will get rid of the dependency.

Comment: @RyanP13 Updated answer, your debounce implementation seems to me to be overly complex. In my previous comment I meant to say: why pass `initialSearch` to `useInstantSearch`

Comment: @RyanP13 Updated answer, the `search.current === value` part can be important because it causes the function to return false when the resolved value did not come from the last **requested** async result (demo in answer with "a" and "ab"). I did not include the CancelTrigger in the demo but you can easily add that.

Answer (score 8):

Since you're using some external function, you can simply ignore the message:

```
useCallback(
  useInstantSearch(...)
, []) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

---

However, you should be using it like:

```
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>(searchQuery);
  const handleDebouncedSearch = useCallback(() => { // -> this
    useInstantSearch(searchTerm, (search, cancelTrigger, searchStillValid) => {
      console.log('instant search', search);
    })
  }, [searchTerm]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Eslint comment is required here because, you're using callback inside useInstantSearch as there's no way to inject them as dependency.

Comment: The suggested code snipped works differently from the original version. useInstantSearch returns a function `(value) => void`. Wrapping it with an inline function `() => ReturnType<typeof useInstanceSearch>` does completely different things.